# Query taxonomies depending on specific category - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to configure a filter navigation where the filters fetched are chosen by the taxonomy 'underkategorier' (Sub categories in Swedish).

The problem I'm having is that I have two pages of which both query different kinds of categories. But for some reason I can't get my list of custom taxonomy links to just list objects within that specific category. One page lists custom posts from Category nr 9 and the other lists custom posts from category 10.

My query is as follows,

```
<?php $queryname = array(
'post_type'      => 'projekt',
'cat'     => 9,
'order'    => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => '-1',); query_posts( $queryname ); ?>
```

And my taxonomy list of links is as follows,

```
     <?php $terms = get_terms('underkategorier'); $count = count($terms);  if ( $count > 0 ){
 echo "<div class='post-tags'><a data-filter='all' class='tax-filter filter'>Visa alla</a>";
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo "<a data-filter='.$term->slug' class='tax-filter filter'>" . $term->name . '&nbsp;(' . $term->count . ")</a>";      
 }
 echo "</div>";} ?>
```

So. I want to display links of category 9 + taxonomy 'underkategorier'. Not posts, but terms. For example if 'underkategorier' has a few terms like, 'buildings', 'parks', railways' I want do display these as links. But only if they belong to category 9 as well. So if there where a fourth 'underkategori' by name 'stadiums' which belonged to a category 10 post, this would not show up on the page that displays category 9 posts.

I am still quite new to these coding parts and I could really use some help and would be very grateful. If my question is fuzzy please let me know and I'll try to rephrase. When I get it right I will share it with you all for future help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find all terms in custom taxonomy 'underkategorier' and then will show terms with post from chosen category.

```
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies(array('name'=>'underkategorier'),'object'); 
foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy->name, 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
    foreach($terms as $term){
        $wpq = array ('taxonomy'=>'underkategorier','term'=>$term->slug, "cat"=>10);
        $myquery = new WP_Query ($wpq);
        $article_count = $myquery->post_count; 
        echo $term->name.' '.$article_count; //with empty ones
        if ($article_count){
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li>".$term->name.' '.$article_count."</li>";
        echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I get it if my question is hard to understand. I have two pages. One listing custom posts within native category 9, and one listing custom posts within native category 10. Both of these pages are to have a filter navigation with links of the custom taxonomy (like tags, not posts). Then I have a jquery setup to filter the posts below when those custom taxonomy links are clicked. I can get the links of the custom taxonomy out just fine, but the problem is that I'm getting them all, and I just want them within the specific pages category (9 on one, and 10 on the other). Is that more clear?

Comment: No problem, it's my fault i can't get you. You want to show list of terms in taxonomy 'underkategorier' which are connected to category 9, right?

Comment: That is exactly what I wan't to do!

Comment: Thank you for your update. Unfortunately it won't do the trick for me. I've googled my way that I might need to tackle the problem this way or someway similar: http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query Have you done this kind of query before? The examples don't show mixing two taxonomies though, or am I wrong?

Comment: my problem is the exact same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574899/get-taxonomy-links-filtered-by-multiple-taxonomy-types

Comment: sure. is 'underkategorier' not a category? BTW stackoverflow is not allowing discussions here, you have not enough reput. to start chat, feel free to contact me @ email

Comment: Ok. I've sent you an e-mail to the info@ address. Thank you for your time